# Rewrite Mod Giving Internal Server Error When Trying to Rewrite Links

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

There are many questions discussing rewrite mod problems. I have read them and none have solved my unique problem. I already have done 3 hours of research to solve it and I am still stuck.

I want to rewrite links in source code retrieved from a remote site through the `file_get_contents()` PHP function.

When I get the source code the link structure is:

```
<a href='javascript:openWindow("index1.php?option=com_lsh&view=lsh&event_id=148730&tv_id=850&tid=34143&channel=0&tmpl=component&layout=popup&Itemid=335","735","770")'  >Link#1</a>
```

I want to rewrite it to:

```
<a href='javascript:openWindow("http://remotesite.com/index1.php?option=com_lsh&view=lsh&event_id=148730&tv_id=850&tid=34143&channel=0&tmpl=component&layout=popup&Itemid=335","735","770")'  >Link#1</a>
```

After some research I thought that rewrite mod would do the trick. I tried to put the code below in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index1\.php?option - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  http://remotesite/index1.php?option [L]
```

However, it give me internal server error.

What I am doing wrong here? Is there is any other way to rewrite the link structure in the way described above?

Comment: I don't think using .HTACCESS is the best solution for you.I think using  regular expression match and string replace is the best.

Comment: i know but now what is the wrong in my htaccess code above

Comment: so what is the best way do do so other than htaccess

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.example\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Mr Ahmed with your code no internal server error but still no change in links

Comment: are you sure the mod_rewrite.c is already loaded in your Apache server? test it by phpinfo(). and try to replace the last line with : `RewriteRule ^http://remotesite/index.php?(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: mod_rewrite.so is uncommented and active in httpd.config and when i tested it py phpinfo() i found mod_rewrite among the loaded modules

Comment: try this : `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.remotesite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://remotesite.com/$1 [L,R]`

Comment: still not working i think we should leave the HtACCESS method and point our research to trying to achieve it in the fine that have the get file content function may be with jquery i my skills at jquery is 0

Comment: I managed to find a work around other than the mod_rewrite method here is the details

I have created a file on my domain and named it `index1.php` this file have the following code 

    `<?php
    header("Location: http://remotesite.com/index1.php?option=com_lsh&view=lsh&event_id=&tv_id=&tid=&channel=&tmpl=component&layout=popup&Itemid=");
    ?>`

and yes it works well but when i click on `Link#1` as in the question it send me to 404 page 

on the remote site as the link fail to get the parameters specified in the link above eg: `Itemid`  `event_id` etc

now how to fix this missing part ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't match against the query string in a rewrite rule. Additionally, mod_rewrite **can not rewrite your content**. You'll need to use some sort of reverse proxy like mod_proxy_html in order to dynamically rewrite your content. The rewrite engine only gets applied when the server receives a request, so the nest that you can do is redirect (or reverse proxy using the `P` flag) once the request reaches your server (the server that has the htaccess file).

None of the rules you have should cause a 500 internal server error, but they won't work anyways because you can't match a query string in a rewrite rule, and additionally, a rule needs a pattern and a target. Your second rule only has a target with no pattern. Most likely, mod_rewrite isn't loaded which would cause a 500 internal server error. Other than that, check your error logs.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index1\.php http://remotesite/index1.php [L,QSA,P]
```

Comment: Mr Jon Lin i have tried your code and also same internal server error

Comment: @user2338253 check your logs, you probably don't have mod_rewrite loaded

Comment: @Mr Jon Lin already checked through phpinfo() and it show that mod_rewrite loaded

Comment: @user2338253 Your error logs will say what is wrong, not your php logs, the webserver's error logs.

Comment: @user2338253 [It depends on your host and your server's setup](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=where+are+my+apache+error+logs&oq=where+are+my+apache+error&gs_l=serp.3.0.0j0i22i30l2.2420.5175.0.6216.25.20.0.0.0.0.283.2331.9j9j2.20.0...0.0...1c.1.11.serp.EOevH-KgQKY)

Comment: I managed to find a work around other than the mod_rewrite method here is the details

I have created a file on my domain and named it `index1.php` this file have the following code 

    `<?php
    header("Location: http://remotesite.com/index1.php?option=com_lsh&view=lsh&event_id=&tv_id=&tid=&channel=&tmpl=component&layout=popup&Itemid=");
    ?>`

and yes it works well but when i click on `Link#1` as in the question it send me to 404 page 

on the remote site as the link fail to get the parameters specified in the link above eg: `Itemid`  `event_id` etc

now how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After more than 6 hours of research I managed to solve this issue  by a way other than the mod_rewrite method here is the details

the trick is simple I just changed from get file content method to curl with more options

below is the code I used:

```
<?php
    //Get the url
    $url = "http://remotesite.com";

    //Get the html of url
    function get_data($url) 
    { 
       $ch = curl_init();
       $timeout = 5;
       //$userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US)AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.X.Y.Z Safari/525.13.";
       $userAgent = "IE 7 – Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30)";
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;

    }

    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    echo '<base href="http://remotesite.com/" />';
    echo $html;
?>
```

the trick to change every relative path to absolute one is here :

```
echo '<base href="http://remotesite.com/" />';
```

thanks @Jon lin, @ahmed for your help